# AXIS2 Set Timeout not Working

Tags: java, timeout, apache-axis

When I try to change the time out to my axis 2 client it doesnt work

The [documentation](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/http-transport.html#timeout_config) says

```
    Options options = new Options();
    options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.SO_TIMEOUT, new Integer(timeOutInMilliSeconds));
    options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, new Integer(timeOutInMilliSeconds));

    // or
    options.setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(timeOutInMilliSeconds);
```

And my Factory

```
String urlWS = MyProperties.getProperties().getProperty("infstatus.url");
InformarResultadoAprovWSStub ws = new InformarResultadoAprovWSStub(urlWS);
ws._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, Boolean.FALSE);
Integer time=Integer.valueOf(MyProperties.getProperties().getProperty("infstatus.timeout"))*60*1000;
Options options = ws._getServiceClient().getOptions(); 
logger.debug("Timeout is "+time);
options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.SO_TIMEOUT, time);
options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, time);
return ws;
```

To be sure, I print the values before invoking WS

```
        logger.debug("Before WS");
        Map<String, Object> mapp = ws._getServiceClient().getOptions().getProperties();
        for(Map.Entry entry:mapp.entrySet()){
            logger.debug(" option "+entry.getKey()+" = ["+String.valueOf(entry.getValue())+"]");
        }

        ws.informar(req);

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        throw new ServiceDependencyException("Error with WS",e);
    } finally {
        logger.debug("After WS");
    }
```

I set the time to 10 minutes or 600000 miliseconds, but the ws raised time out after 90 secs aproxs

```
2017-06-13 16:14:44 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG InformaStatusDelegate:53 - Before WS
2017-06-13 16:14:44 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG InformaStatusDelegate:56 -  option __CHUNKED__ = [false]
2017-06-13 16:14:44 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG InformaStatusDelegate:56 -  option SO_TIMEOUT = [600000]
2017-06-13 16:14:44 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG InformaStatusDelegate:56 -  option CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = [600000]

2017-06-13 16:16:08 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG InformaStatusDelegate:64 - After WS
```

And the StackTrace

```
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.impl.httpclient3.HTTPSenderImpl.sendViaPost(HTTPSenderImpl.java:216)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:121)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:403)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:234)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:431)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:399)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:150)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at ja
```

The client was created with Axis2 1.7.5 databinding method ADB

What is wrong?

I tried too with

```
options.setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(timeOutInMilliSeconds);
```